# マルウェアを作るにはどのような勉強をしたら良いですか？

Tags: security

マルウェアを作るにはどのような勉強をしたら良いですか？
セキュリティですか？pythonですか？もちろん技術的な興味です。
作る方法では無くて、作るのに必要不可欠な知識のことです。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10218410590

Comment: 日本においては無限アラート事件のように、マルウェア作者でなく、リンクを貼って紹介した者が逮捕されます。従ってこのような質問を扱うと回答者にリスクが生じるため、SOで扱うべきではないと提案します。

Comment: @チャンユー さん、Wikipedia の[「マルウェア」の項目](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2)を見ても分かるように、単にマルウェアと言うと「悪意のあるソフトウェア」をまとめて指しているものであり、回答として答えるには範囲が大きすぎます。まずは疑問点を絞ってください。そして、日本には通称[「ウイルス作成罪」と呼ばれる罪があり](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E6%AD%A3%E6%8C%87%E4%BB%A4%E9%9B%BB%E7%A3%81%E7%9A%84%E8%A8%98%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E7%BD%AA)、その幇助となりえるような回答は法律的にも道徳的にも投稿できないことをご理解くださいませ。

Comment: [ヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help) にも記載の通り、当サイトは "**誰か一人でも世の中の他のプログラマーに役に立つような内容**" を共有する場を目指しています。 / 一方で「マルウェア」というのは(明確に)**悪意をもった**ソフトウェアの総称ですから、この手の質問は受け入れられないと思います。 / また、モラルの話を抜きにしても過去の質問を含め内容が曖昧または範囲が広すぎるため回答が付けづらいと判断されています。

Answer (score 1):

なんとか幇助にならない程度で

マルウエアとは malicious software のことで「悪意のあるソフトウエア」であれば何であれ全てマルウエアと呼んでいるようです。

```
int main() { }
```

でも悪意を持って作ればそれはマルウエア ([c89](/questions/tagged/c89) では終了値不定だし) 。

マジレスするに必要な知識はコンピュータ関連のなんでもすべてということになるでしょうし、特定の分野のマルウエアを作るならその分野の知識。まあこんな場で訊いている時点で限りなく今は無理っしょ？　数年勉強してもまだ全然知識っつか経験っつか、いろんなものがすべて足らないっす。

# 本格的なマルウエアでなくてよいなら「無限アラート事件」もマルウエア扱いされちゃいましたし調べてみては？

Comment: 既存の脆弱性を使ったマルウェアだったら簡単ですよね？